# On Linux, vim would search #include files automatically for auto-completion but on Windows not

Tags: autocompletion, microsoft-windows, plugin-ctrlp

I use vim on Linux and Windows. Strangely, on Linux (Ubuntu), when I write C/C++ code, vim would search the included file for auto-completion (Ctrl-P), even if I don't add anything related in my `.vimrc`. But on Windows, it doesn't behave that way. I have tried to add `set path+=$INCLUDE` in my `_vimrc` (`$INCLUDE` is in my path and it's the path of the C/C++ header file), but that doesn't work either.

Comment: What is the output if you run `:set complete?`? If there is no `i` for searching included files for autocompletion, adding `set complete+=i` in your `_vimrc` might help. Does your problem happen with exactly the same `vimrc` file on Linux and Windows? Also, do you by chance happen to use tpope's sensible.vim?

Comment: @cbaumhardt No I don't use the same vimrc file on Linux and Windows, because on windows I add something like `behave mswin`. But besides those operating-system related directives, all other are the same. And I am not using `sensible.vim`. Have you ever had the same problem?

Comment: What happens if you use an explicit path, instead of `$INCLUDE`, and that path is not the path to the file, but to the include *folder*? An equivalent to Linux's `/usr/include` path. Things should be OK when you can place cursor on a line such as `#include <stdio.h>` and `gf` can open that file.

Comment: @VanLaser yes, it work.

Answer (score 4):

with the help from VanLaser in the comments above,I eventually find out how to do that on Windows:

```
set path+=C:/Program\\\ Files\\\ (x86)/Microsoft\\\ Visual\\\ Studio\\\ 12.0/VC/include
set path+=C:/Program\\\ Files\\\ (x86)/Microsoft\\\ SDKs/Windows/v7.1A/Include
```

just add these two lines in my vimrc then it would work. Those two `C:/xxxxx` are my system `%INCLUDE%` path, where all the necessary C/C++ header files located. Note the different version of Visual Studio and change those two path correspondingly. Also note that those `\\\` are necessary to escaped the space(see `:h 'complete'` (not `:h complete()`) for more information).

Also, make sure that option `i` is in your complete options(use `set complete?` to see, and the default is `complete=.,w,b,u,t,i`. See `:h 'complete'`)

Comment: If you don't like the triple slashes you could also do `let &path = path . ',C:/Program Files (x86)...,C:/...'`, using a single quoted literal string after a `let` with string concatenation. The two C: bits are your two paths and there's a comma separating each path including these from what's existing.